# WindowInsetsCompat in AndroidX Core v1.5.0-alpha02

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, windowinsets

With the release of WindowInsetsCompat in AndroidX Core v1.5.0-alpha02, what's the equivalent of

```
view.windowInsetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.ime())
```

that does not give a `@RequiresApi(R)` Annotation warning?

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets(view)?.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
```